# Python gui button (tkinter) function is being run when program is executed and not onclick

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

i'm currently learning python/tkinter and I have two buttons working correctly but my final button is assigned to a function, which is supposed to run on click but it instead runs when the program is executed and then will not run when the button is clicked. I have looked at a couple of other threads and cannot work out why mine wont work.

Thanks a lot

```
def onclickSelectSheet(): 
    test()

buttonSelectSheet = Button(topFrame, text="Select an information sheet", command=onclickSelectSheet(), bg = '#CDCDCD')
buttonSelectSheet.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute a Button-command on click, you need to set the `command` option as follows:

```
Button(..., command=lambda: onclickSelectSheet(),...) # with parenthesis
```

OR

```
Button(..., command=onclickSelectSheet,...) # without parenthesis
```

Using parenthesis `()` without `lambda` executes the function as soon as the `Button` widget is defined

Comment: Thank you very much, short and sweet explanation and makes complete sense!